# how long are triplets?

Tags: rhythm

[image: swing rhythm]

If I'm not wrong this should be a swing rhythm, but how long are the triplets actually to fit in the 4/4 beat?
Do triplets have always a fixed length in the beat or does it depend on how you play them?

Comment: This kind of triplets (eighth triplets) last for 1/3 of a quarter. So, in each beat you have 3 triplets.

Comment: I don't get it, it would mean: 1/4 + 1/3 +1/4 +1/3 = 7/6 ???

Comment: @Milo_666 Make sure you catch that those eighth rests are eighth-note *triplet* rests. As such, this measure is 1 + (1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3) + 1 + (1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3) = 4 beats.

Comment: ok so it means a triplet always take such as 1/4 note

Comment: @Milo_666 The general rule is that a group of three triplets lasts the duration of two of those regular note values. So a group of three eighth-note triplets will last the duration of two normal eighth notes, and thus a quarter note.

Comment: Don' t play the triplets in a mathematical way. They stand for swing, as you say. So play them just swinging: da _ da_ba, da_da_ ba,

Comment: @Richard ok so it means that a GROUP OF TWO eighth-note triplets will last the duration OF TWO quarter notes

Comment: @Milo_666 If by "group of two eighth-note triplets" you mean "two groups, each with three eighth-note triplets", then yes! ...sorry, I'm just trying to be 100% clear :-)

Comment: Despite the fact that mathematically all three are equal in length or timing, *swing* feel doesn't just use that meter as is. There's different emphases in hard swing, where the ratio isn't actually 66/33, but could be nearer to 70/30. It usually depends on the tempo - and of course, who's playing.